# avconv "Error while opening encoder for output stream" for subtitles?

Tags: video-encoding, avconv

I'm trying to convert a video changing the audio codec from aac to ac3_fixed:

```
avconv -i input.mkv -c:v copy -c:a ac3_fixed output.mkv
```

However this commands aborts after showing the following output:

```
avconv version 11.2-6:11.2-1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
built on Jan 18 2015 05:12:33 with gcc 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu2)

...

Duration: 02:01:58.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1916x804 [PAR 1:1 DAR
479:201], 23.98 fps, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
Stream #0.1(spa): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp (default)
Stream #0.2(spa): Subtitle: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000
Stream #0.3(eng): Subtitle: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000

Stream #0.0: Video: libx264, yuv420p, 1916x804 [PAR 1:1 DAR
479:201], q=2-31, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
Stream #0.1(spa): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1, s16p, 448 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc56.1.0 ac3_fixed
Stream #0.2(spa): Subtitle: ass, 200 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc56.1.0 ass
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> ac3 (ac3_fixed))
Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (? (?) -> ssa (ass))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:2 - maybe
incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

I guess the problem is related to the encoding of the subtitles, but I
don't know what is necessary to fix it. I couldn't find any
information on the internet about this issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe specifying to avconv you dont want to convert your subtitle with `-c:s copy` will solve your issue.

I dont no what's the default behavior...